# Populate a table using PDFBox

Tags: pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to generate invoices from a PDF template. The template has a table by the name "tbl_itemization". Is it possible to reference the table name in the runtime and then programmatically add rows to it?